# Is this rust on a new truck's underside normal?

Tags: ford, rust

I bought a new 2015 Ford F-150 and am wondering if this rust is common to the central Texas area?  Is this anything I should try to fix? [image]

Comment: Just me being a silly about all how we gamify human knowledge.

Comment: Indeed.  This is massive gamification.  I'll trade knowledge for points and accolades.   lol.  Best to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rust your photo depicts is normal for the steel components on any vehicle.  New or used.

You can go review the undersides of new vehicles at a car lot and see that many will show rust right off the delivery truck.

Most of the cast steel components will show signs of iron oxide anywhere in the country.  Oxygen and Iron is all that it really takes.

Best of luck.